# How to check if schema already created in JanusGraph?

Tags: database, janusgraph

Trying to check if schema in **JanusGraph** installed, so I checked **JanusGraph** docs "Schema and Data Modeling" as I can see I can print schema, but I don't know if there flag as "**schema installed**" or "**modified**". So how do I check if schema in **JanusGraph** installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "mgmt" object we can check "getRelationTypes", if it there then schema exists

```
mgmt.getRelationTypes(RelationType.class).iterator().hasNext()
```